# Objects depth sorting in isometric game

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, isometric, tile-engine

I have isometric tile game engine (diamond map style) and I need to sort objects what I draw. My objects are 1x1, 2x1, 4x2. How can I do it based on this code?

```
for (int osaY = 0; osaY < mapSize; osaY++)
        {
            for (int osaX = 0; osaX < mapSize; osaX++)
            {
                int x = osaX * 32;
                int y = osaY * 32;

                PlaceObject(thisObject, CartToIso(new Vector2(x, y)), new Vector2(osaX, osaY));
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the code you're showing matters, but generally you can get away with drawing an isometric scene purely based on the viewport's Y axis, with higher items being drawn first. You may also have layers, but within a layer, that should remain true. It should only get difficult if you have elevation, but that can be treated as layers as well.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you got a screenshot? What is the code intended to do?

Answer (score 0):

How I solve sortings:
 1. Creating IDisplay interface and adding it to every class which handles displaying `Draw(SpriteBatch batch)`
 2. Creating a `DisplayManager` which has `Add`,`Remove`,`Draw` methods and as many `layers`**(List of IDisplay objects)** as you want. Personally, the mid layer is the layer where I sort my stuff. So I can put stuff behind sorted objects, and before sorted objects.
 3. In the `Main` class which handles the drawing, call the `DisplayManager's Draw` function, which will run through the `layers`(Lists) and `IDisplay` items and call the `Draw` function on every item.

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
DisplayManager.Draw(spriteBatch);
spriteBatch.End();
```

And then in the DisplayManager:

```
public static void Draw(SpriteBatch batch){
   for (i = 0; i < bottom.Count; i++)
   {
       bottom[i].Draw(batch);
   }
   //Gets the model from the IDisplay item, and then it's Y position, and orders
   //the sort layer(list) by that.
   sort = sort.OrderBy(o => o.getModel.Position.Y).ToList();
   for (i = 0; i < sort.Count; i++)
   {
       sort[i].Draw(batch);
   }
   for (i = 0; i < top.Count; i++)
   {
       top[i].Draw(batch);
   }
}
```